# Click to show more - maybe JS?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure what language or how to do this, but I am looking to have a word on a page, and when clicked, it will reveal more underneath. If it is clicked again, that stuff will hide away again? Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind this will possibly: hinder visitors without JavaScript, hinder search engines and (if using a framework like people suggest) ass Kilobytes of code, for a trivial function. But of course coolness may be more important.

Comment: I think its good for you to post this, i hadn't really thought of it.
So when would using JS be good? What's the point if you have to worry about users without it?

Comment: IMHO: You add JavaScript to the "finished" site for additional "nice to have" functionality. BTW, I have been too harsh. What you want can be done without hindering non-JS visitors if you either have the complete text visible when there is no JS, or have the "more" link link to a separate page with the complete text.

Comment: No i understand what you mean.
There are ways around it.
So you make the site for users without JS.
Then add little bits for users with it, without hindering those without?

Comment: Exactly. I've just posted an answer with an example on how to do it without hindering non-JS users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, you will need to manipulate the `display` CSS property of the element to be hidden/revealed:

```
<span id="showHide">Show</span>
<div id="foo" style="display:none">Here is some text</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("showHide").onclick = function() {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("foo");
    if(theDiv.style.display == 'none') {
        theDiv.style.display = 'block';
        this.innerHTML = 'Hide';
    } else {
        theDiv.style.display = 'none';
        this.innerHTML = 'Show';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @downvoter - What, not enough jQuery? Or is the code I provided broken in some way?

Comment: it is funny people down voting just by saying **not enough jQuery**. This should not happen.

Comment: ;) Duplicate Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785386/how-do-i-display-field-when-i-click-on-a-link-javascript

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend javascript and using jQuery .show() & .hide() methods:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/slicker-show-and-hide

Answer (score 2):

you could do this with jQuery, here a ready to use example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8sDLg/

```
$(function() {$('div.more').hide()
  $('a.showmemore').click(function(){
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle()
})})
```

Comment: Seems a good answer but I am confused about where i put the jQuery?

Comment: you can put it in your head of the HTML file.

`<script type="text/javascript">
  the script, 
</script>`

dont forget to load the jquery library first:
http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Put the stuff in a `div` with style `display:none;`. In the `onClick` handler of the word (can be link or a button), toggle the display style between `''` (which means 'default') and `'none'`

Answer (score 1):

**[I created a demo for you here.](http://jsbin.com/ukelo3)**

You could use **[jQuery](http://jquery.org)** for that and make your life easy:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Show/Hide</a>
<div id="mydiv">Some content</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $('#link').click(function(){
    $('#mydiv').slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

As can be seen, the `slideToggle()` does the trick there for you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Executive summary**:  use a framework plugin

**Long version**:

You could use javascript -- more likely in a combination with a javascript framework, like jQuery.  This would involve adding a click handler to the word (actually a span tag around it) and having a way to retrieve the extra information to show as a tooltip -- there are plenty of plugins for this.  Search for "jquery tooltip" here or using google: here's one [example](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/).

Alternatively, you could simply surround the word with the span tag and add a title attribute to the tag.  Hovering over the word (actually the tag) would bring up the browser's default tooltip.  This might be an easy way to get started with it -- in fact, this could be the start of the javascript solution.  Using the tag for the click event and taking the data from the title attribute -- probably by storing the title in jQuery data on page load, then grabbing the text from the data on click so that you don't have a conflict with the browser's tool tip behavior.  Many of the plugins operate this way.

Answer (score 0):

Quick idea how to do it when avoiding a JS-only solution. I'm using jQuery here, because it is faster to code in, but as I mentioned above, if this is your only JS functionality it would only add a heavy-weight file for some trivial extras.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
    $(".article .additional")
      .hide()
      .before("<a href='#'>")
      .prev()
        .text("more")
        .click(function() {
           $(this).next().toggle()
         })
  });
</script>

<div class="article">
  <h2>Some headline</h2>
  <p>Some intro text that is always visible</p>
  <div class="additional">
    <p>Some extra text that is hidden by JS</p>
    <p>But will stay visible if the visitor doesn't have JS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see, the HTML is completely stand-alone. Only if JavaScript is supported, a "more" link will be added and the additional content hidden, so that non-JS users still can read all the text and don't have an useless "more" link.

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant approach using pure HTML and CSS without JavaScript.

HTML:

```
here goes text before 
<label class="details">
    <input type="checkbox" /><span>here come some details</span><em> </em>
</label> 
and after
```

CSS:

```
.details input,
.details span {
    display: none;
}
.details input:checked~span {
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px gray;
}
.details em:after {
    content: "show...";
}
.details input:checked~em:after {
    content: "...hide";
}
```