# How do I display field when I click on a link? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

how do I create it so that when I click "report user", a box displays and it shows a list of reasons why to report the user and a submit button.

I rarely use javascript...can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is to toggle the CSS display with Javascript. This is the break down of the below code:

1. Attach an event to the links when the page loads. This is what the `window.onload` part does.
2. Identify the links and box with `document.getElementById`
3. Use an anonymous function to capture the display toggle
4. Toggle the display with `style.display`.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <title>Onclick Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function(){
     var link =  document.getElementById('rulink');
     var box  =   document.getElementById('box');
     var close = document.getElementById('close');  
     link.onclick = function(){
         box.style.display = 'block'
       }  
       close.onclick = function(){
         box.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style>
    div{  
      display:none;  
      background:#f00;  
      width:100px;  
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="rulink">report user</a>
      <div id="box">
      <ul>
        <li>abc</li>
        <li>def</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close">Close</a>
    </div>
    </body>
   ```

Comment: Is there an easy way to copy-paste or export from TextMate into the Stackoverflow Markdown Field? Formatting is rough.

Comment: I've never had problems doing it this way: soft tabs (4 spaces) then copy then paste then click the 'code' button in SO. When taking only part of some code that's already indented... I do an intermediate step in a new document. Could use some bundle love!

Answer (score 0):

Look into `onclick` events.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into jquery, it makes javascript much easier.  Using jquery you could perform that using one line of code such as:

```
$('.<link class>').click(function(){$('.<list class>').show()});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, but it's pretty crude:

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('something').style.display='inherit';return false" >###</a>
<input style="display:none" type="text" id="something"  />
```

That's the "hard way", but understanding how it works is important.

It is worth it to use a JavaScript framework. Jquery is the most popular and it can seriously make doing any UI work WAY easier.

You can shorten that onclick to:

```
$('#something').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.getElementById("showHide").onclick = function() {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("foo");
    if(theDiv.style.display == 'none') {
        theDiv.style.display = 'block';
        this.innerHTML = 'Hide';
    } else {
        theDiv.style.display = 'none';
        this.innerHTML = 'Show';
    }
}​
</script>

<span id="showHide">Show</span>
<div id="foo" style="display:none">
<form method="post">
    <h3>Here are some reasons</h3>
    Blah: <input type="checkbox"/><br />
    Blah: <input type="checkbox"/><br />
    Blah: <input type="checkbox"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8TNmn/2/ and see [Click to show more - maybe JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757999/click-to-show-more-maybe-js)

Comment: Don't you need a window.onload or a onclick='doSomething()'?

Comment: There is an anonymous function attached to the show/hide element's click event. Why post 'dupe answer' under the original answer which I posted? I know the implementation is exactly the same, but I provided a working example with the type of markup the OP was talking about, *and* linked to the original question. My intention was not to cheat :)